# An internal error occurred during: "Launching test". org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel In Eclipse

Tags: android, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10

Installed eclipse plugin with the referance [this link](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/)

but i got error when run project as Blackberry Android Launch

Please check screenshot [image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know when this message appears? I guess that the .bar has been created and you have the message when it tries to upload it to device. Or does it happens sooner?

Comment: @Hithredin yes you right . .bar has been created and try to run in Simulator then i got this message.

Comment: i have checked that java have  1.6.0_39 and Eclipse have 3.8.2.v20130116 Version and also BB plugin is latest version

Comment: Could you download the Command line tools from here: https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/ ?
And run: "jre\bin\java.exe" -Xmx512M -jar  CommandLineTools\lib\BarDeploy.jar  -installApp -device %simulator_IP% -package %BarFilePath%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that eclipse.ini AND the path variable of Windows uses the version 6 of Java, not the 7.

Make sure you have the supported version of eclipse: Eclipse version 3.8 for the latest version of the bb plugin