# Trying to set up run configurations for an android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am working on an android app project that I cloned from bitbucket. However, when I try to set up the run configurations to run it in an emulator, I cannot do that. What I tried so far was to right click on the project -> run as -> Run configurations... and then click Android Application which creates a new configuration. Now when I try to select the project by browsing, the project is not available there. Then if I just type in the project name manually and try to run it, a dialogue box comes up saying, "An internal error occurred during: 'Launching projectName'". Does anyone know what could be the issue?

EDIT: As for target virtual device, I set it to "launch on all compatible devices", however under "Automatically pick compatible device" there are no devices listed even though I have created an AVD.

Comment: have you selected the target virtual device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723104/an-internal-error-occurred-during-launching-test-org-eclipse-jdt-debug-core

Comment: you said you cloned it.  Make sure the clone included a valid eclipse project file.  Otherwise, according to eclipse, it's just a directory with code and not a 'project'.

Comment: @Tom by valid project file, do you mean the .project file or project.properties file?

Comment: yeah, usually when you clone a repo, eclipse asks how you want to take the code, new project, existing project..etc

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't show up in the folders,maybe it isn't set-up as a project.

The standard procedure,as you said is:

Click on Run Configurations. Then name the configuration and select the project by browsing through the folders.

As for target virtual device,select the most recent Android version you want your app to run on.